# I can't find out what's wrong with my code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a bubble sort algorithm and I keep on encountering bugs. I mostly get errors with the first for loop, it claims it is an unqualified id. I also get some erros with one of my variables needing to declare a type again in the for loop how ever this causes issues with the entire code.

```
bubble-sort.cpp:12:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’
   12 | for (int hop=0; hop <= 10; hop++){
      | ^~~
bubble-sort.cpp:12:17: error: ‘hop’ does not name a type
   12 | for (int hop=0; hop <= 10; hop++){
      |                 ^~~
bubble-sort.cpp:12:28: error: ‘hop’ does not name a type
   12 | for (int hop=0; hop <= 10; hop++){
      |                            ^~~
bubble-sort.cpp:28:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
   28 | };
      | ^
```

I get these errors from this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array [5] = {19,3,90,1,9};

class BubSor {

public:

    int temp;
    for (int hop=0; hop <= 10; hop++){
        while (hope >=10 ){
            for (int j=0; j <=5; j++;){
                if (array[j]>array[j+1]){
                    array [j] = temp;
                    array [j+1] = array [j];
                    temp = array [j+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
};

int main (){

    BubSor object;
    object  ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have statements, e.g. `for` loops, outside of a function body. You have one in the middle of a class definition; that makes no sense, and won't compile.

Comment: You'll find code is much easier to read and understand if you learn how to properly ident it. It makes it much easier to understand the organization and logic.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's not the only issue. `hope` was never declared, and even if it was supposed to be `hop`, that `while` loop will only execute on the last pass of its parent loop.

Comment: I follow the [Allman Indentation Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style). It is a bit more bulky than other coding styles but following it all but eliminates whole families of compiler errors and bugs. What ever you use, the point is be regular. A lot of bugs stick out like a sore thumb when surrounded by order.

Comment: No wonder Page is stepping down; I remember a time when one could literally locate *thousands* of working bubble-sort examples from which to glean knowledge with just a few keystrokes.

Comment: Did you see my edit? I explained the parts of your code that needed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Comments that can help you improve on your original code:

```
// avoid making global variables. Only constants that are used throughout your program should be made global.
//Also when making an array like this instead of using 5 do the following
// const int SIZE = 5;
// int array[SIZE] = {19,3,90,1,9};
// this way you can use the size later on
int array [5] = {19,3,90,1,9};

class BubSor {

public:
// you have to put this in a function
    int temp;
// bounding it by 10 is not correct because this number will change
// and you also the most passes you will ever have to make will be the size of the array
    for (int hop=0; hop <= 10; hop++){
// you do not need this while loop
// also hope should be hope
        while (hope >=10 ){
// this should be bound by the size of the array -1, because you are comparing to j + 1, otherwise you will go over the size of the array
            for (int j=0; j <=5; j++;){
                if (array[j]>array[j+1]){
                // here you should place it into temp instead
                    array [j] = temp;
                    // this should be done in reverse order
                    array [j+1] = array [j];
                    // swap the next line too
                    temp = array [j+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}; // you do not need the extra ; here
}; // this one is necessary because it is a class

int main (){
    BubSor object;
// here you need to call the function that is inside the class
    object  ;

    return 0;
}
```

A version of a possible implementation of the suggestions that I gave above:

```
// no global variable array

class BubSor {

public:
// the code is wrapped in a reusable function called sort which takes
// as parameters an array and its size N
    void sort(int* array, const int N)
    {
        int temp;
        bool swapped = true; // if you haven't made any swaps then the array is already sorted
        // bound the for loop by the actual size of the array
        for (int hop = 0; hop < N && swapped; hop++) {
            swapped = false;
            // inner for loop goes only to the size -1 because
            // we are comparing j to j + 1, otherwise we go over the size
            // of the array
            for (int j = 0; j < N-1; j++) {
                // if unordered swap
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    temp = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    // good practice to place it in a const
    const int N = 13;
    int arr[N] = { 19,3,1,2,3,11,10,9,3,4,90,1,9 };
    BubSor object;
    // use the sort function to sort the array
    object.sort(arr, N);
    // print the array to see if the function is working
    for (int x : arr)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I realize how stupid I've been now, I completely forgot what the use for classes we're I was mistaking them for functions. I really appreciate the comments you've made on my code. It's really going to help me in improving my codes structure. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I am glad that I was able to help you.